# How to find factors of a matrix determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, factoring, roots-of-unity

I'm working on some problems for fun and came across this problem I'm stuck with. Here's the question: Use row operations to show that $ x + \omega y + \omega^2 z $ is a factor of $ \Delta $, where $ \Delta $ is defined as: $$ \Delta \equiv \begin{vmatrix}
x & y & z \\
z & x & y \\
y & z & x \\
\end{vmatrix} = x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz $$

and $ \omega $ is a cubic root of unity.

What I've tried:

I first applied the row operations $ R_1 \to R_1 + R_2 $ and then $ R_1 \to R_1 + R_3 $. This allows us to rewrite the determinant as:

$$ \Delta = (x + y + z) \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
z & x & y \\
y & z & x \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Then I can transpose since the determinant is unaffected by transposing to get:

$$ 
\Delta = (x + y + z) \begin{vmatrix}
1 & z & y \\
1 & x & z \\
1 & y & x \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

I then wanted to get zeros in the (2,1) element. I know $ 1 + \omega + \omega^2 = 0 $ since $ \omega $ is a cubic root of unity, so I applied the row operations $ R_2 \to R_2 + \omega R_3 $ and $ R_2 \to R_2 + \omega^2 R_1 $ which gives:

$$
\Delta = (x + y + z) \begin{vmatrix}
1 & z & y \\
0 & x + \omega y + \omega^2 z & z + \omega x + \omega^2 y \\
1 & y & x \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Then to set the (3,1) element to zero, I performed the row operation $ R_3 \to R_3 - R_1 $ where I got to my final point.

$$
\Delta = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & z & y \\
0 & x + \omega y + \omega^2 z & z + \omega x + \omega^2 y \\
0 & y - z & x - y \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

I was hoping to get a hint on how to proceed from here. I should mention that I know how to factor $ x + \omega y + \omega^2 z $ from $ x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz $, but I don't know how to obtain $ x + \omega y + \omega^2 z $ from row operations alone. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Diagonalize the matrix (for generic $x,y,z$).

Comment: Ahh ok got it thanks a ton! I'm still open to solutions that don't require knowledge of diagonalization too because I think technically students haven't quite reached eigenvalues/eigenvectors at this point yet

Comment: Okay, try the following: First, $x+y+z$ is a factor, since the sum of all rows is divisible by $x+y+z$ in each entry. However, if we replace $y$ and $z$ by $\omega y$ and $\omega^2 z$, then the determinant gets multiplied by a constant factor (why?), but $x+y+z$ becomes $x + \omega y + \omega^2 z$. Hence, $x + \omega y + \omega^2 z$ must, too, be a factor.

Comment: Notice that in the second row of your reduced matrix you can divide by $x + \omega y + \omega^2 z$ because $\omega( x + \omega y + \omega^2 z) = z + \omega x + \omega^2 y$.

Comment: @layabout Thanks! this is very helpful and I think pretty is much the actual solution to the problem. But rather than dividing out $ x + \omega y + \omega^2 z $, I can take out a factor of $ x + \omega y + \omega^2 z $ from the second row which would leave me with a factor of $ \omega^2 $ in the (2,3) element since $ \omega^2(z + \omega x + \omega^2 y) = x + \omega y + \omega^2 z $

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a really interesting puzzle!

Firstly the matrix you are tackling is in the family of [circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), which is interesting and useful in applied math.

A property of these matrices is that it's diagonalized by the DFT matrix. In other words, each of its eigenvector is a geometric series of the $n$th unit root.
$$
C=\begin{bmatrix}
c_0 & c_{n-1} & c_{n-2} & ... & c_2 & c_1\\
c_1 & c_{0} & c_{n-1} & ...& c_3 & c_2\\
&&...&&\\
c_{n-2} & c_{n-3} & c_{n-4} & ...& c_0& c_{n-1}\\
c_{n-1} & c_{n-2} & c_{n-3} & ... & c_1&c_0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
v_j=[1,\omega^j,\omega^{2j},...\omega^{(n-1)j}]^T\\
\lambda_j = c_0+c_1 \omega^j+c_2 \omega^{2j}+ ... + c_{n-1}\omega^{(n-1)j}
$$
Then given
$$
\Delta =\prod_i\lambda_i
$$
I think you can easily prove your target with $n=3$